# how can i show result for list of self-joined class in master-detail?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, master-detail, stimulsoft

i have an entity clss for stuffs:

```
  public partial class Stuffs
{
    public Stuffs()
    {
        this.Stuffs1 = new HashSet<Stuffs>();
    }

    public long StuffID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> StuffParentID { get; set; }
    public string StuffTitle { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Stuffs> Stuffs1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Stuffs Stuffs2 { get; set; }
   }
```

when i send List to stimulereport , i want to show result in master-detail or parent-child.

these are my stimule code:

```
 public ActionResult PrintTreeStuffsResult()
    {
        List<Stuffs> StuffListResult = db.Stuffs.ToList();

        StiReport StiRpt = new StiReport();
        StiRpt = GetStiReportTree(StuffListResult);
        return StiMvcViewerFx.GetReportSnapshotResult(StiRpt);
    }
  public StiReport GetStiReportTree(List<Stuffs> StuffsTreeResult)
    {
        StiReport StiRpt = new StiReport();
        string a = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/Admin/StuffsTreeResult.mrt");
        StiRpt.Load(a);
     StiRpt.RegBusinessObject("Stuffs", StuffsTreeResult);

        StiRpt.Dictionary.SynchronizeBusinessObjects();
        StiRpt.Save(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/Admin/StuffsTreeResult.mrt"));
        return StiRpt;
    }
```

i saw in internet many samples that explains about two table with relation , forexample customer and order. but i have one table with self-joined.
how can i do that? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next method:

```
StiRpt.Dictionary.SynchronizeBusinessObjects(2);
```